# How to access device on i2c multiplexer? C# Windows 10 Iot Core

Tags: pi-3, i2c, windows-iot

I'm looking at communicating with sensors via Adafruit TCA9548A breakout.

Mr Wood posted this great class: [How to use Adafruit TCA9548A 1-to-8 I2C Multiplexer Breakout in C#?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/57693/how-to-use-adafruit-tca9548a-1-to-8-i2c-multiplexer-breakout-in-c/71033#71033)

It seems to be selecting the device and channels fine, my issue is after a successful connection, how would I address the device i would like to communicate with?

I have 3 of the same sensor connected to different channels on the multiplexer.

From Python or Arduino C, each transmission of communication states the address to communicate with, however in C# I have to define this before any read/write is done.

The problem I have is that it seems to me when I communicate with my sensor, I am sending a byte which is switching the channel on the multiplexer and then communicating with the wrong sensor. I'm getting data just its coming from the wrong sensor. The sensor I seem to continuously get data from is the sensor on channel 2.

I am completely stuck. I have tried initialing the I2C device each time I want to communicate with it, I tried sharing the I2C device between all the sensors (current setup) nought.

This is my current code https://pastebin.com/pSQXTdEm
MainPage code https://pastebin.com/C0pLT80r

Comment: Your code is too long and too complicated for such an application, so I didn't really go through it. But I think if you are using  `Tca9548a.SelectAddress(0x70, 0x01)` to select the multiplexer, it is what you get, i.e. Channel 2. To address Channel 1, you need to pass in `0x00`, or Channel 3 with `0x10`.

Comment: Yes, i understand that part. It seems to be selecting the correct channel, but from what I understand, I need to open a new I2CDevice with the sensors I2c address after this selection. The library in C# says I cannot change this 'on the fly'. So I initalise a new I2CDevice with the sensors address, this seems to then reset the whole port selection on the multiplexer. I want to i2c though the i2c multiplexer. I've already done this in another language, its converting it in C# is my issue.

Comment: Just reading your comment further, 0x01 = 2? 0x00 = 1? 0x10 = 3? What am I missing here? I thought 0-7 for the 8 channels on the multiplexer. 0x00 would be channel 0 upto 0x07 would be channel 7?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I mistaken it as binary (0x10 as binary 3).... You are correct in channel selection.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is code related and not Raspberry Pi specific.